# How can I extract a 1 dimentional row from a multidimentional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I currently have a 3 dimensional matrix and I want to extract a single row (into the third dimension) from it by index (say `matrix(2,1,:)`). I initially anticipated that the result of this would be a 1 dimensional matrix however what I got was a 1 by 1 by n matrix. Usually this wouldn't be a problem but some of the functions I'm using don't like 3D matrices. For example see the problem replicated below:

```
threeDeeMatrix=rand(3,3,3);
oneDeeAttempt=threeDeeMatrix(1,1,:);
norm(oneDeeAttempt)
```

Which returns the error message:

```
Error using norm
Input must be 2-D.
```

This is because oneDeeAttempt is

```
oneDeeAttempt(:,:,1) =

    0.8400


oneDeeAttempt(:,:,2) =

    0.0700


oneDeeAttempt(:,:,3) =

    0.7663
```

rather than `[0.8400 0.0700 0.7663]`

How can I strip these extra dimensions? The only solution I can come up with is to use a loop to manually copy the values but that seems a little excessive.

Answer (score 2):

## Using permute to rearrange the matrix

The solution (which I found in the final stages of asking this) is to use permute which rearranges the order of the dimensions (similar to `a=a'` for 2D matrices). Once the unit dimensions are last they are stripped from the matrix and it becomes 1 dimensional.

```
oneDee=permute(oneDeeAttempt,[3 1 2]) %rearrange so the previous third dimension is now the first
%the matrix is now 3 by 1 by 1 which becomes 3
```

## Using squeeze to remove leading singleton dimensions

As pointed out by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040424/how-can-i-extract-a-1-dimentional-row-from-a-multidimentional-matrix/24040425?noredirect=1#comment37062110_24040425) `squeeze` will very simply remove these leading singleton dimensions without having to worry about which dimensions are non singleton

```
oneDee=squeeze(oneDeeAttempt);
```

Comment: It's simpler to use [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html). It automatically removes all (heading) singleton dimensions, except for 2D arrays (row vectors are unaffected)

Comment: @LuisMendo Nice! I always say theres still a selfish reason for a self answered question: in case someone else has a better solution. If you wish to post that as an answer I will accept

Comment: definetly squeeze. that’s why it exists

Comment: I've posted self-answered questions before, and I know selfishness if not the motivation for them. You've taken the time to post the question; go ahead and include `squeeze` in your answer if you like :-)